# selective row sum matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any efficient numpy way to do the following:
Assume I have some matix `M` of size `R X C`. Now assume I have another matrix
`E` which is of shape `R X a` (where `a` is just some constant `a < C`), which contains row indices of
`M` (and -1 for padding, i.e., every element of `E` is in `{-1, 0, .., R-1}`). For example,

```
M=array([[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6],
         [7, 8, 9]])

E = array([[ 0,  1],
           [ 2, -1],
           [-1,  0]])
```

Now, given those matrices, I want to generate a third matrix `P`, where the i'th row of `P` will
contain the sum of the following rows of `M` : `E[i,:]`. In the example, `P` will be,

```
P[0,:] = M[0,:] + M[1,:]
P[1,:] = M[2,:]
P[2,:] = M[0,:]
```

Yes, doing it with a loop is pretty straight forward and easy, I was wondering if there is
any fancy numpy way to make it more efficient (assuming that I want to do it with large matrices,
e.g., `200 X 200`.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you have 2 or more `-1` per row in `E`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to sum with indexed on original array and then subtract out the summations caused by the last indexed ones by `-1s` -

```
out = M[E].sum(1) - M[-1]*(E==-1).sum(1)[:,None]
```

Another way would be pad zeros at the end of `M`, so that those `-1` would index into those zeros and hence have no effect on the final sum after indexing -

```
M1 = np.vstack((M, np.zeros((1,M.shape[1]), dtype=M.dtype)))
out = M1[E].sum(1)
```

If there is exactly one or lesser `-1` per row in `E`, we can optimize further -

```
out = M[E].sum(1)
m = (E==-1).any(1)
out[m] -= M[-1]
```

Another based on tensor-multiplication -

```
np.einsum('ij,kli->kj',M, (E[...,None]==np.arange(M.shape[1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could index `M` with `E`, and [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) where the actual indices in `E` are greater or equal to `0`. For that we have the `where` parameter:

```
np.sum(M[E], where=(E>=0)[...,None], axis=1)

array([[5, 7, 9],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

---

Where we have that:

```
M[E]
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[7, 8, 9],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[7, 8, 9],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```

Is added on the rows:

```
(E>=0)[...,None]
array([[[ True],
        [ True]],

       [[ True],
        [False]],

       [[False],
        [ True]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the fastest but maybe educational: The operation you are describing can be thought of as matrix multiplication with a certain adjacency matrix:

```
from scipy import sparse

# construct adjacency matrix
indices = E[E!=-1]
indptr = np.concatenate([[0],np.count_nonzero(E!=-1,axis=1).cumsum()])
data = np.ones_like(indptr)
aux = sparse.csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr))

# multiply
aux*M
# array([[5, 7, 9],
#        [7, 8, 9],
#        [1, 2, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Inspired by this matrix multiplication, got me thinking and ended up with a tensor multiplication one.

Comment: @DIvakar you one-upped me there regarding the sparsity of the auxiliary matrix ;-)